# plot xts Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to plot an xts object but I get an error about years.. The xts object just has a numerical value and a POSIXct index. Below is the code that shows the xts and the error when trying plot. Any ideas on what needs to be done to a xts object to properly plot?

```
xTest<-as.xts(35, Sys.time())
xTest
##                           [,1]
## 2013-04-07 18:19:19.37238   35
class(xTest)
## [1] "xts" "zoo"
class(index(xTest))
## [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

plot(xTest)
##  Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 4):

What is your goal? Is there a problem that the `plot.xts` function will not plot fewer than 3 points? The error gets thrown by the `xts::axTicksByTime` because the minimum number of breaks is 2. Attempts to pass a different argument to `axTicksByTime` are frustrated by the coding in `plot.xts` which has no `...` mechanism in it.

Comment: I'm trying to plot trading data across multiple contracts that are not at consistent time intervals. The example provided was a simplification of the plot issue. Plotting just the date works without any issue as shown below.  `>plot(index(xTest))`