# Is it possible to plot a single second period in xts (sub-second series)?

Tags: r, xts

I get an error "Error in if (on == "years") { (from #17) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" when trying to plot sub-second series in xts. That is, my xts object only includes observations for the same second:

```
                         value
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0000 471295
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0000 471296
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0002 471297
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0002 471298
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0004 471299
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0004 471300
2013-04-23 13:09:29.0006 471295
```

A similar question about this error was already asked [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871059/plot-xts-error-in-if-on-years-missing-value-where-true-false-needed) but I'm not clear if there is a workaround to plot sub-second series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
R> zzz <- xts(100+cumsum(rnorm(10)), Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(10))/1e3)
R> zzz
                               [,1]
2013-04-30 10:15:15.588007  98.9827
2013-04-30 10:15:15.588615 100.0029
2013-04-30 10:15:15.589559 100.6558
2013-04-30 10:15:15.590063  98.7353
2013-04-30 10:15:15.590466 100.0204
2013-04-30 10:15:15.590787 100.5416
2013-04-30 10:15:15.591345 100.5990
2013-04-30 10:15:15.591624 100.7908
2013-04-30 10:15:15.592415 101.8566
2013-04-30 10:15:15.592915 102.4576
R> plot(zzz)
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
R> traceback()
4: endpoints(x, cl, ck)
3: axTicksByTime(x, major.ticks, format.labels = major.format)
2: plot.xts(zzz)
1: plot(zzz)
R>
```

So the error comes from the axis formatting.  You can either override this, suppress it by now asking for axis to be drawn or just do

```
R> plot(as.zoo(zzz))
```

which works fine as your series is univariate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same issue as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974436/problems-plotting-intraday-ohlc-data-in-r-with-quantmod-chartseries).  A solution is to specify `major.ticks`

```
> set.seed(1)
> zzz <- xts(100+cumsum(rnorm(10)), .POSIXct(0) + cumsum(runif(10))/1e3)
> plot(zzz, major.ticks="seconds")
```

[image]

Comment: I actually use `plot.zoo` waaaay more than `plot.xts`.  `plot.xts` from the [xtsExtra](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118) package is really cool, but it's less developed/less stable than `plot.zoo`.